# How can I calculate the width of stand required for a Christmas tree based on its height?

Tags: centre-of-gravity

Given the height and / or weight of a cut tree, what is the best way to calculate the width of stand required to keep it upright?

I have no engineering background, but have been trying to think of a way to work it out. I think the key elements are center of gravity, and I also need to decide what amount of force I am expecting (it will be indoor, so only accidental knocking) to counter.

The tree in question is a 15ft spruce, however if there is a ratio or method I can use to calculate stand width I can do the rest myself.

Comment: In theory, with the expected amount of tree flex and disturbances, you do not want the center of gravity of the tree to move past the edge of it's base.

Comment: hang it from the ceiling upside down ... lol

Comment: @DKNguyen  actually the C.M. of the tree + base.  A big massive base makes a difference too.  And of course if the tree isn't firmly affixed to the base, other bad things happen

Comment: @CarlWitthoft True.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Amazon and some hardware stores sell tree stands rated for the height and weight of the tree.

For example, this is a stand for a 15-foot tall tree from amazon.
Its legs are 30inches long.

'

[image: tree sttand]

Comment: And yet they make assumptions about the symmetry of the tree and how good consumers are at mounting it vertically.

Answer (score 1):

#### This needs to be solved empirically.

There isn't going to be a specification for "how out of balance is okay."  The issue isn't the tree's center of gravity being off, it's really how stable the tree needs to be to support people knocking into it.  Things like this are best solved by doing, which, as mentioned in the question comments, have already been solved by current manufacturers.